# How do I return a range from a function within a Class?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, for-loop

How do I return a range from a function within a class?

When I print out the function from my class, only 97 prints, not the full range to 122.

```
class Characters:
    def lower_case(self):
        for i in range(97, 123):
            return i
result = Character()
print(result.lower_case())
```

Comment: Make sure to format your code into a code block before you post.

Comment: You return immediately from your method. Returning exists the function.

Comment: You can unpack a range using `list` like `print(list(range(97, 123)))`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will try to unpack it first. Next time, I will format my code into a block. This is my first post.

Comment: Thank you all. I resolved it completely. All of your suggestions were a great help. Keep up the great work. :)